# Gauss-Seidel Smoother for Problems with jumping coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

for a project I am working on a "robust" multigrid implementation, i.e. a implementation which achieves fast convergence even for problems with discontinious coefficients. My first problem is:

$ - \nabla \cdot a(x, y) \nabla u(x, y) = 0 \text{ on } \Omega$

$u(x, y) = f(x, y) \text{ on } \partial \Omega$

Right now, it is all very simple. $\Omega$ is the unit square and $a$, the coefficient function, is

$ 
     a(x, y) =\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1, & x < 0.5 \\
         100, & x \geq 0.5 \end{array}\right. .
$

As BC, I chose
$f(x, y) = sin(\pi x) cos‚(\pi y)$

I tried to implement this directly via multigrid, and it didn't converge. In order to debug it, I wanted to just use the GaussSeidel smoother as a solver. Unfortunately, it didn't converge either. According to the paper I use for my implementation (Robust multigrid methods for nonsmooth coefficient elliptic linear systems by Chan and Wan), the GS smoother should work if it smoothes along the discontinuity.

It obivously doesn't work. So I am a little bit lost on why it is not working. Are there any ideas what conditions have to be fulfilled in order to solve such a PDE with jumping coefficients?